# Is it possible in deep learning to train on a subset of training set in order to find the best hyper-parameters?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

In classic machine learning, it is not uncommon to do a search for hyper-parameters by training different configurations on a small subset of training set. Usually, for each set of hyper-parameters, a k-fold cross validation is done over a small subset of training set. However, in deep learning, models are usually very hungry of data.

So, my question is that do you think is it still possible to use the same strategy in deep learning? What is your experience?

Comment: This is probably not a particularly good practice for any machine learning method that has regularisation parameters, as the amount of regularisation required depends on the size of the training set.  There are ways to approximately compensate for this, but it will be only an approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but as you noticed, the deep learning models usually work best with large samples. So your subset would need to be large as well. With insufficient data, the model would underperform and wouldn't help for hyperparameter tuning.